# Python/Openpyxl - comparing cells in Excel with diff format (text vs number)

Tags: python, excel, comparison, openpyxl

I would like to compare two cells in Excel using Python/[openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). And I’m using the simple formula below.

```
x=1
print(ws.max_column,ws.max_row)
for i in range(1,ws.max_column):
    for j in range(3,ws.max_row+1):
        y=x+1
        if ws.cell(j,x).value != ws.cell(j,y).value:
            print("Errors found: ")
            print(ws.cell(j,x), ws.cell(j,x).value, ws.cell(j,y).value)
            print(ws.cell(j,x).style)
            print(ws.cell(j,y).style)
    x+=2
```

The issue is the result I’m getting for printout:

```
Errors found:
<Cell 'Sheet1'.S228>  None

Normal

Normal
```

I can’t find a reason why it reports a difference when both cells in Excel are blank.

Comment: I could duplicate what you see by simply typing a **single** quote into the cell. A single quote **at the start** of the cell value denotes the contents as text and is not shown by Excel. So entering just a single quote in the cell means it looks empty and the cell value has no length but the value is **''** and not **None**. Not saying this is what you are experiencing but it can definitely happen.

Comment: I checked now cell S228 and T228 which are being compared and both of them seems to be blank when I look at FX field on top of Excel. But I also used condition formatting to see if they are duplicated, and excel also says they are not. Which is totally weird, I mean if Im gonna make blank each cell manually than this does not makes sense at all. Any additional ides from you @moken?

Comment: Update:

I just checked in excel these cells with formula =ISBLANK(). One cell returns value true and other false

Both of them appear the same, but Im not able to distinguish them with python. Does anyone has an idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Half-hearted solution - [LINK](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2917-excel-cells-appear-blank-but-are-not-really-blank.html):

I used kutools and used function "To Actual" that made **all blank but not blank cells** to blank ones.

A full answer would be to find a way to do the same with openpyxl.

Comment: Without knowing for sure what the state of the effected blank cells is, suggestions for detecting the cells is only a guess however I'd expect that at least in all cases the length of the value **len(cell.value)** is Zero. Therefore if the cell meets that criteria you could just then set it to None **cell.value = None**.

Comment: @moken yes you are right. LEN value is 0 for all of them. Will try with that option. Thank you